# CSS @import "~materlize-css" | Using Webpack | No style being made

Tags: css, wordpress, webpack, sass, materialize

I'm using Sage, a WordPress framework, and it lets you choose during creation some css frameworks, but I want to use Materialize CSS instead.

It uses Webpack to build and combine the `.scss` files into one. I did an `npm install materialize-css` so it's in my `node_modules`. In my project structure, I made an scss file that's used to import the module basically.

I also have bulma in this build, included via the original creation, so I can try to see how the structure is setup. It uses the following import statement:

```
@import "~bulma";
```

This works. I'm so confused about how this works. I think the `~` (tilde) tells Webpack something, but I don't know what. What I figured is that Webpacks checks the package.json file or something and finds it in the node_modules.

I've tried `@import "~materialize-css";` with no luck.

Can someone explain what the heck Webpack is doing? Haha, because I can't find any documentation on this.

Here are the node_module folder structures, maybe this has something to do with it:

[image: node module folder structures]

Perhaps the root of Bulma is `bulma.sass` yet for Materialize-CSS, there's no file, it's in `sass/materialize.scss`.

If needed, here's the github for the Sage framework, the `webpack.config.js` is in the *build* folder: https://github.com/roots/sage/tree/master/resources/assets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specific the file you want to import also like this

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
@import "~toastr/toastr";
```